# How to get the max and min dates in a collection of documents using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I have a collection of documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5826182e2e94e0aefc541924"),
    "calls" : [ 
        {
            "call_date" : "2016-08-16 00:00:00.000",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-11-11T19:12:46.905Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2016-11-11T19:12:46.905Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5826182e2e94e0aefc541925")
        }
    ],
        [ 
        {
            "call_date" : "2016-08-19 00:00:00.000",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-11-11T19:12:46.905Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2016-11-11T19:12:46.905Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5826182e2e94f0aefc541925")
        }
    ],
        [ 
        {
            "call_date" : "2016-08-07 00:00:00.000",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-11-11T19:12:46.905Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2016-11-11T19:12:46.905Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5826182e2j94e0aefc541925")
        }
    ]

}
```

I want to be get the minimum and maximum dates across the entire collection. So in the case above, I would like to get 2016-08-07 00:00:00.000 as minimum date and 2016-08-19 00:00:00.000 as the maximum date. I am not sure if I have to use some sort of aggregate function or a regular query. Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess I could sort the collection by date and pick the least and greatest? I will try that and see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use Laravel's Collection:

```
$collection = collect($arr['calls']);
```

And then, you can use the `max` and `min` methods with the relevant key as its argument:

```
$collection->max('call_date');
$collection->min('call_date');
```

But I am not sure this will work for date strings. If not, something like this should work:

```
$value = function($item) { 
  return strtotime($item['call_date']); 
};

$collection->max($value);
$collection->min($value);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Did the first suggestion work? Or the second?

Comment: first. I saved it as a date field.