# Laravel timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have these data in my database

```
2018-03-14 01:22:48 
2018-03-14 01:22:44 
2018-03-14 01:22:40 
2018-03-14 01:22:36 
2018-03-14 01:22:32 
2018-03-14 01:22:28
2018-03-17 01:22:28
```

and I'm using a Laravel on my web site.I just wanted to output one sepecfic date coming from all the dates

this is I want to attain:

```
2018-03-14
2018-03-17
```

Comment: This question is far from clear. How do you have that data stored? Why is that value the one picked?

Comment: You can use either a group by clause with a time conversion using SQL or have PHP convert the date.

Comment: @njhelloworld, please mark whichever answer was most correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your data is retrieved as a String, you can do the following:

```
<?php
$datesString = "2018-03-14 01:22:48 2018-03-14 01:22:44 2018-03-14 01:22:40 2018-03-14 01:22:36 2018-03-14 01:22:32 2018-03-14 01:22:28 2018-03-17 01:22:28";
$datesArray = [];
$dateTimeArray = explode(" ", $datesString);
foreach($dateTimeArray as $index=>$date) {
    if($index % 2 == 0) {
        $datesArray[] = $date;
    }
}

$firstDate = $datesArray[0];
$lastDate = $datesArray[sizeOf($datesArray)-1];

echo $firstDate." - ".$lastDate;
?>
```

In case your data is retrieved as an array, you can do the following:

```
<?php
$dateTimeArray  = [
    "2018-03-14 01:22:48", 
    "2018-03-14 01:22:44", 
    "2018-03-14 01:22:40", 
    "2018-03-14 01:22:36",
    "2018-03-14 01:22:32",
    "2018-03-14 01:22:28", 
    "2018-03-17 01:22:28"
];

$datesArray = [];

foreach($dateTimeArray as $dateTime) {
   $datesArray[] = explode(" ", $dateTime)[0];
}

$firstDate = $datesArray[0];
$lastDate = $datesArray[sizeOf($datesArray)-1];

echo $firstDate." - ".$lastDate;
?>
```

**Edit:**

or if you want that to be done in the database side, you can just query the min and max values of the date field. as answered in the following   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557063/how-to-get-the-max-and-min-dates-in-a-collection-of-documents-using-jenssegers-l?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

An example of the native SQL that would achieve that result:

```
 SELECT DATE(t.mycol) AS mycol 
   FROM mytable t
  GROUP
     BY DATE(t.mycol)
```

There are other query patterns that would achieve the same result, for example:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT DATE(t.mycol) AS mycol 
   FROM mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it shows here in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-unique), you would use the `unique` method on your found results.

Let's say your dates are coming from a users table:

```
DB::table('users')
  ->where('company', 'Google')
  ->unique('date')
  ->values()
  ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Eloquent Model file:

```
<?php // User.php for example

class User extends Model {

    protected $casts = [
        'dateColumn' => 'date',
    ];

    // You can now use $user->dateColumn and you will get back dates
    // $user->dateColumn->format('Y-m-d'); // 2018-03-14

}
```